# Was the room of requirement created by Helga Hufflepuff?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Who created the room of requirement? I know one of the founders must have created it but do we know which one? There are theories that Helga Hufflepuff created it, is that true? Or was it added later on by someone else?

Comment: Care to elaborate on these "theories that Helga Hufflepuff created it"?

Comment: It just says that because Slytherin created the chamber of secrets Hufflepuff created the room of requirement